# Categorical Description of Open Subspaces

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology

In **Top**, the monos are the injective maps and the regular monos are the subspace inclusions. Is there a (similarly pithy) categorical description for the *open* subspace inclusions?

Comment: An open inclusion $U \hookrightarrow X$ is the same as a map $X \to S$, where $S$ is the Sierpinski space (the two-point space which is neither discrete nor codiscrete). The equivalence, analogous to a subobject classifier, comes by pulling back along the inclusion of the open point into $S$. Maybe not quite as pithy as one might like... One might be able to describe open maps via lifting properties though.

Comment: @TimCampion fair enough, though I was hoping for a characterization separate from S, so that we could say that S classifies such arrows.

Comment: A _necessary_ condition in terms of mapping properties is this. There is a well-known (contravariant) functor $F$ from Top to the category of complete Heyting algebras. Now _if_ $j\colon U\to X$ is an open inclusion in Top, then $j$ is mapped by $F$ to the epi $F(j)$ $=$ $\mathrm{Ouv}(X)\twoheadrightarrow\{ O\in\mathrm{Ouv}(X)\colon O\leq U\}$. It might be fruitful to analyse whether this can be made into a characterization of open inclusions.

Comment: Roughly speaking, the suggestion was to think about dualities between monos and epis w.r.t. some known and natural functor.

Comment: Regarding my vague suggestion about lifting properties: note that open inclusions are not closed under products, so they do not form a right orthogonality class. But I think they are closed under colimits and cobase change, so they _ought_ to form a left orthogonality class. However, maps $X \to Y$ which have the right lifting property with respect to every open inclusion seem to be very weird...

Comment: The subspace inclusion $A \subset X$ is open iff it is a local homeomorphism. But unclear how to purge the notion of "open set" from the definition of "local homeomorphism".

Comment: Actually, @PeterHeinig, can use your suggestion, since there is a notion of "local homeomorphism" of complete heyting algebras (locales) which doesn't reference open sets. My one concern is that the functor from $Top$ to complete heyting algebras is defined with reference to open sets.

Comment: @ColinZwanziger: good to hear. While this is not what you are asking for (dictionary between attributes of maps and attributes of morphisms), let me mention a known categorical description of open subsets: open subsets are precisely the coalgebras of the interior-endofunctor. Let $\mathsf{C}$ denote the small posetal category with objects precisely the subsets of $X$ and let $\mathrm{int}$ denote the endofunctor sending any subset to its interior w.r.t. the topology of $X$. Then the open subsets bijectively correspond to the coalgebras of $\mathrm{int}$. This is almost tautological, though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450193). The main idea is to define Sierpinski objects as small spaces.

Comment: I'm confused by a few things in the answer you link to. 1) The codiscrete category with two elements meets your definition of a Sierpinski object (a connected object with two global points), but I don't see where you consider this. 2) I don't understand what you mean by "distinguishing two isomorphic Sierpinski spaces from each other". Do you mean you want to distinguish the two points $x,y: 1 \to S$ of the Sierpinski space $S$ from each other? 3.) You mention certain maps that do certain things to $y$; are you claiming there are no maps that do similar things to $x$?

Comment: 1) Corrected. 2) Well we have to say which point is closed and which point is open. Notice that my first definition of a Sierpinski is completely symmetric. So it cannot be complete. 3) For $Top$ this is the case.

Comment: I think the Sierpinski space can also be defined as the lax pushout of $Id_1$ along itself. (Considering **Top** as a poset-enriched category where $Hom(X,Y)$ is ordered pointwise using the specialization order on $Y$).